# Render component by function pointer and pass props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

I have an array of pointers, `componentArray`, but I'm struggling to figure out the syntax to both render them in `ParentComponent`

```js
function Component1() {
    return(
        <h1>Hello from Component 1</h1>
    );
}

function Component2() {
    return(
        <h1>Hello from Component 2</h1>
    );
}

export const componentObject = [{
    name: "Component1",
    pointer: Component1
}, {
    name: "Component2",
    pointer: Component2
}];

function ParentComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.entries(componentObject).map((ChildComponent) => (
                <span>{ChildComponent[1]() DOESNOTWORKPROP="Test"}</span>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
};
```

The above will work if you remove `DOESNOTWKRPROP="TEST"`, but will not work when trying to add props to the children.

Comment: Show how you pass the children to the parent.

Comment: Updated with more details

Comment: Try something like `componentArray.map(Child => <Child prop={value} />)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should not call directly `ChildComponent` as a function. You should use the "tag syntax", as follows:

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {componentObject.map(({ pointer: ChildComponent }) => (
                <ChildComponent DOESWORKPROP="Test" />
            ))}
        </div>
      );
};
```

Note that the variable used in the tag should use PascalCase for react to accept it, thus the renaming as `ChildComponent` after destructuring `pointer`.

Here is the related documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime

Bonus: you should provide a prop `key` to element generated with `map`. Here you can use the name of your components ;)

```
<ChildComponent key={ChildComponent.name} DOESWORKPROP="Test" />
```

---

Going further, when you call the function directly here:

```
<span>{ChildComponent[1]() DOESNOTWORKPROP="Test"}</span>
```

Your component is executed immediately and returns static JSX, as if your code became:

```
<span>{<h1 DOESNOTWORKPROP="Test">Hello from Component 1</h1>}</span>
```

That why your props don't apply: they are passed to a static JSX element, not to the dynamic rendering process of your component

Comment: Sincere apologies - in an effort to simplify my question and make it more legible I changed the object to an array not realizing that was actually key to the problem. I have updated my original question to reflect that. Sorry again

Comment: I adapted my answer to your edited question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `componentObject` is an array so you just need to use `map()`.

And try this way:

```
function ParentComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {componentObject.map(({ pointer }) => {
                const ChildComponent = pointer;
                return <ChildComponent DOESNOTWORKPROP="Test" />
            })}
        </div>
      );
};
```

Comment: Sincere apologies - in an effort to simplify my question and make it more legible I changed the object to an array not realizing that was actually key to the problem. I have updated my original question to reflect that. Sorry again